# Python list of indicies in list

Tags: python, list, indexing

Here is my code

```
a = [10,11,12]
index = [0,2]
print(a[index])
```

I expect `10,12` as output, but get error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Is is possible to achive something like this in python? I know I can do it with list comprehension, but want something simpler. The problem looks so pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
In [1]: from operator import itemgetter

In [2]: a = [10, 11, 12]

In [3]: index = [0, 2]

In [4]: itemgetter(*index)(a)
Out[4]: (10, 12)
```

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with list comprehensions?

```
In [1]: a = [10, 11, 12]

In [2]: indices = [0, 2]

In [3]: [a[i] for i in indices]
Out[3]: [10, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want special semantics, you can create a list subclass:

```
class PickList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return PickList([super(PickList, self).__getitem__(k) for k in key])

a = PickList([10,11,12])
index = [0, 2]
print a[index]
```